# TypeError Object id is not JSON serializable

Tags: json, django, url, serialization, django-templates

I have a Django view that is raising an error when the template tries to render:

> TypeError:  is not JSON serializable

(Where 76 is the id field)
Here is the view

```
def view2(request, model1object_id):
    model1object = Model1.objects.get(pk=model1object_id)

    # HERE

    session_object = request.session.get('content')
    if session_object:
        del request.session['content']
    request.session['content'] = model1object


    context = {
        "model1object": model1object,
        ....
    }    
    return render(request, 'app/template2.html', context)
```

Here's my model for Model1:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    date_field = models.DateField()
    another_field = models.CharField(max_length= 50, default="...")

    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self.id) or u''

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('app:model1', kwargs={'id': self.id})
```

EDIT: Traceback ->

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 235, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py", line 50, in process_response
    request.session.save()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 82, in save
    obj = self.create_model_instance(data)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 68, in create_model_instance
    session_data=self.encode(data),
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 91, in encode
    serialized = self.serializer().dumps(session_dict)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/signing.py", line 95, in dumps
    return json.dumps(obj, separators=(',', ':')).encode('latin-1')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 250, in dumps
    sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <Model1: 76> is not JSON serializable
```

thanks

Comment: The traceback is telling you that the error is encountered when serializing the session. You haven't shown what `TimeSheet` is or how it is added to the session.

Comment: seems like you have a dictionary with a TimeSheet object in it, which cannot be converted to JSON, JSON only admits strings, numbers, booleans and null. This means you would have to serialize the TimeSheet object into a valid JSON dictionary

Comment: @Alasdair ah always do that when I copy over. TimeSheet is my Model1. Forgot to change that one.

Comment: Why do you think the error is triggering on that line of the template? The traceback is telling you that the error occurs when the session middleware tries to save the session. As I said before, you haven't shown the code where you added the model instance to the session.

Comment: @Alasdair I was messing around with that at the time, so I naively thought it was that. I've made an edit... isn't `model1object = Model1.objects.get(pk=model1object_id)` where I add the model instance? :S

Comment: The traceback suggests that the error is occurring when the session is saved, but you haven't shown any code that modifies the session and explains the error. I can't help from the code you have shown.

Comment: @Alasdair oh god...... I'm an idiot. session above. Forgot about that, I wanted to pass that content to another view which handled the post data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is because you are trying to save a model instance in the session, and the session middleware cannot serialize it to JSON.

```
request.session['content'] = model1object
```

It may be enough to store the id of the object instead of the object itself.

```
request.session['content_id'] = model1object.id 
...
# retrieve from db later
model1object = Model1.objects.get(id=request.session['content_id'])
```

If you need to store more information in the session than the id, then you'll have to convert it to a format that is JSON serializable. For a simple model, it might be easiest to create a Python dict.

```
request.session['content'] = {
    'id': model1object.id,
    'name': model1object.name,
    ...
}
```

For more complicated models, you could look at the docs on [serializing Django objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/serialization/#serializing-django-objects).